# Write then wait for response serialport nodejs

Tags: node.js, serial-port, port

i'm trying to use serialport.js and I wondered how can it be possible to write and wait response from the other side because all is asynchronous.

My problem is I must know to which response is associated the send message.

I think that involve to manage when response never send from the other part.

Should I use queue system ? is there a example to do it or a library ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something to parse the stream.  I do this by implementing a writable stream which fires events for the parts of the stream data that I want.

How you do this specifically depends on the protocol you're trying to implement.

Comment: Do you have a beginning of an example juste to have the way to do it ? thank you.

Comment: @JuChépa It's highly variable.  Without knowing anything about your protocol, there is no way to provide an example other than `stream.pipe(yourParserStream)`.

Comment: Sorry @Brad, in fact, I would send some commands in writing but for each commands, i would have their associated response by the other nodejs server for example. For example, Command1 sending then wait response associate to Command1 and then send Command2... 
Hope i'm clear

Comment: @JuCuhépa In this case, I would send the command and then set a state variable with the expected response and length.  Are the responses' length fixed?  Or are they delimited by something like a line?  In any case, buffer the incoming data until you have the expected length, then parse it, and then perform the appropriate action.  What protocol are you using?

Comment: all commands and responses are fixed with specific length . 
I think I began to understand

Comment: Perfect. So as data comes in, add it to a buffer. When the buffer length is greater than or equal to the length you need, split off that chunk and parse it.

Comment: and then I just have to put the transmitter in reading  to wait the response from the other side ?

Comment: @JuChépa Serial ports are generally full-duplex so you don't have to tell anything to listen.  It should always be listening, receiving, and buffering data.  When you get a complete message, you parse it.  If you need to know what command caused the message to come back, then you just track that last command in a state variable.